Confused about how flutter build/web differs from what is served while debugging
I'm developing a flutter web app. I've had no problems deploying the myapp/build/web directory and serving it via nginx, although a few emojis are not loaded correctlt.
However, my main issues is that debugging from within Android Studio doesn't work.  Running as follows:

seem serves a page that generates the error

doesn't update build/web and worse it seems to be serving entirely different files (e.g. FontsManifest.json) is loaded by chrome attached to the debugger/AndroidStudio) which is never requested when build/web is served via nginx.
What does the debug server actually serve and why is it different to build/web?
(flutter clean; flutter pub get does not fix this)
My web/flutter_bootstrap.js is modified as:
{{flutter_js}}
{{flutter_build_config}}

const loading = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(loading);
loading.textContent = "Loading ...";

_flutter.loader.load({
  onEntrypointLoaded: async function(engineInitializer) {
    loading.textContent = "Initializing engine...";
    const appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
      useColorEmoji: true,
    });

    loading.textContent = "Running app...";
    await appRunner.runApp();
  }
});

to allow loading of emojis (what is missing in production).
